# Buying another kit instead of 8293-1: Motor Set?

Tags: technic, shopping, power-functions

I want to get some motors but don't know if it is a better idea to buy `8293-1: Motor Set` or try obtain motors from some other sets. Is there any kit challenging 8293?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several alternatives, and you can combine several approaches if you've got the cash:

1. You can buy individual Power Functions parts from [a LEGO shop](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Power-Functions-ByCategory) or from various other vendors. The advantage is that you'll get the specific parts that you're interested in. The down-side is that it'll probably cost you more than buying a set like 8293.
2. You can buy a bundle from eBay. Several vendors make up their own kits that are similar to 8293 but with a slightly different mix of components.
3. You can buy a set that contains Power Functions. This tends to be fairly cost-effective if you're interested in the parts that the set contains, but with the disadvantage of a larger initial outlay. Of course, you could re-sell anything you don't want if you're prepared to put in some effort. The other advantage of buying a kit is that you'll probably learn some new techniques during construction.

If you go for (3), some of your options are:

- 8110 Mercedes-Benz Unimog U 400
- 9397 Logging Truck
- 9398 4X4 Crawler
- 41999 4x4 Crawler Exclusive Edition

Personally, if had the cash, I'd go for a 41999 (assuming it is still available). It includes [a great selection](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Ow6ct1yCXgw/UdAupr-OPNI/AAAAAAAAQxQ/qMyxgJshJK0/s640/blogger-image--1982346445.jpg) of Power Functions components including remote control and IR receiver, a lot of generally useful parts, several exclusive parts (perfect for eBay?) and... well, it's just *very* cool.

Comment: I actually ended up buying 9398, it includes two less power-functions units compared to 41999 but that was not available to me.

Comment: I'm pleased you found something that meets your needs.